# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: react-redux

I keep getting this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') when I try to export this function

```
export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user.name
```

in my react project. Please How do I Fix this

Answer (score 1):

user object probably null

```
export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user?.name
```

Answer (score 0):

User object is null, that is causing issue, you can check if user object is not null

```
export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user && state.user.name
```

More cleaner approach you can use optional chaining operator

```
export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user?.name
```